# Django formtools wizard produces blank page (No error returned)

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-formwizard

I'm trying to use the formwizard in formtools package with no success (I was able to do it when the package was inside Django in earlier versions).

The only response I got is:

```
[23/Jan/2016 11:06:50]"GET /registration/wizard HTTP/1.1" 200 13729
```

and a blank page. No errors in browser or Eclipse console.

There's no way of googling without errors. Please help.

Thanks in advance

**What did I do?**

Firstly, I installed the formtools package with pip:

```
django-formtools==1.0
Django==1.8.3
```

Following the instructions of the official docs:

1. Define form classes

   **registration/forms.py**

   ```
   class StepForm1(forms.Form):
       first_field = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
       second_field = forms.CharField()

   class StepForm2(forms.Form):
       message = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea)
   ```
2. Create WizardView

   **registration/views.py**

   ```
   TEST_TEMPLATES = {"test_step_1": "registration/test_step1.html", "test_step_2": "registration/test_step2.html", }

   from formtools.wizard.views import SessionWizardView

   class WizardTest(SessionWizardView):
       template_name = 'registration/test_wizard.html'

       # Return templates for each step
       def get_templates_name(self):
           return [TEST_TEMPLATES[self.steps.current]]

       # Method called when all is done
       def done(self, form_list, **kwargs):

           # return HttpResponseRedirect('/url-to-redirect-to/') 

           # We return the final template with the info
           return render_to_response('test_done.html', {
                                      'form_data':[form.cleaned_data for form in form_list],
                                      })

       # THESE METHODS BELOW ARE NOT NEEDED, BUT COMMENTED FOR FUTURE USE

       # Not strictly needed. Returns data for a step
       # or None if form is not valid
       # def get_cleaned_data_for_step(self, step):
       #     return None

       # Form data postprocessing in a concrete wizard step
       # def process_step(self, form):
       #     return self.get_form_step_data(form)

       # Handles value from a step before storing them into wizard
       # def get_form_step_data(self, form):
       #     return form.data
   ```
3. Create the templates

   **registration/test_step1.html**

   ```
   <h1>Two fields form</h1>
   <input id="first_field" name="first_field">
   <input id="second_field" name="second_field">
   ```

   **registration/test_step2.html**

   ```
   <h1>Message form</h1>
   <input id="message" name="message">
   ```

   **registration/test_wizard.html**

   ```
   {% extends "person/alumnos.html" %}
   {% load i18n %}

   {% block head %}
       {{ wizard.form.media }}
   {% endblock head %}

   {% block content %}
   <p>{% trans "Step {{wizard.steps.step1}} of {{wizard.steps.count}}" %}</p>

   <form action="" method="post">
   {% csrf_token %}

   {{ wizard.management_form }}

   {% if wizard.form.forms  %}
       {{ wizard.form.management_form }}
       {% for form in wizard.form.forms %}
           {{form}}
       {% endfor %}
   {% else %}
       {{ wizard.form }}
   {% endif %}

   {% if wizard.steps.prev %}
   <button name="wizard_goto_step" type="submit" value="{{ wizard.steps.first }}">{% trans "Beginning" %}</button>
   <button name="wizard_goto_step" type="submit" value="{{ wizard.steps.prev }}">{% trans "Previous step" %}</button>
   {% endif %}
   <input type="submit" value="submit"/>

   </form>

   {% endblock %}
   ```
4. Add 'formtools' to my INSTALLED_APPS

   **settings.py**

   ```
   DJANGO_APPS = (
       # Default Django apps:
       'django.contrib.auth',
       'django.contrib.contenttypes',
       'django.contrib.sessions',
       'django.contrib.sites',
       'django.contrib.messages',
       'django.contrib.staticfiles',
       'formtools',                 # <===== HERE

       # Useful template tags:
       # 'django.contrib.humanize',

       # Admin panel and documentation:
       'django.contrib.admin',
       # 'django.contrib.admindocs',
   )

   # Apps specific for this project go here.
   LOCAL_APPS = (
       'person',
       'registration',
       'teaching',
       'utils',
   )

   # See: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#installed-apps
   INSTALLED_APPS = DJANGO_APPS + LOCAL_APPS
   ```
5. Point my URLconf at your WizardView as_view() method.

**registration/urls.py**

```
from registration.forms import StepForm1, StepForm2
TEST_FORMS = [("test_step_1", StepForm1), ("test_step_2", StepForm2), ]

from registration.views import WizardTest

# I tried in two ways, none of them worked

urlpatterns = patterns('',
         url(r'^wizard$', WizardTest.as_view(TEST_FORMS), name='wizard_test'),
         url(r'^wizard2$', views.wizard, name='wizard_test'),
)
```

For the second way...

**registration/views.py**

```
def wizard(request):
    return WizardTest.as_view(TEST_FORMS)(request)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found my error. I typed badly the method name for getting the templates. It's not

```
get_templates_name(self)
```

but

```
get_template_names(self)
```

It wasn't getting any templates, but when returning to server it was answering with HTTP 200 OK, because it didn't found any error.

I also found that my templates for every step should extend the main wizard template in order to work correctly. With the 'done' template is not necessary.

Answer (score 2):

What example are you following for your templates? [The basic layout is in the docs](http://django-formtools.readthedocs.org/en/latest/wizard.html#creating-templates-for-the-forms). Try starting with something like this (both pages can use the same template if you are fine with the fields generated by formtools):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Form Wizard</title>
    {{ wizard.form.media }}

</head>
<body>
{% load i18n %}
<p>Step {{ wizard.steps.step1 }} of {{ wizard.steps.count }}</p>
<form action="" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
<table>
{{ wizard.management_form }}
{% if wizard.form.forms %}
    {{ wizard.form.management_form }}
    {% for form in wizard.form.forms %}
        {{ form }}
    {% endfor %}
{% else %}
    {{ wizard.form }}
{% endif %}
</table>
{% if wizard.steps.prev %}
<button name="wizard_goto_step" type="submit" value="{{ wizard.steps.first }}">{% trans "first step" %}</button>
<button name="wizard_goto_step" type="submit" value="{{ wizard.steps.prev }}">{% trans "prev step" %}</button>
{% endif %}
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="{% trans "submit" %}"/>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I edited the post to show the wizard template. It doesn't work yet

Comment: My last comment was edited because it may have been misunderstood. I'm at the same situation and the main template for the form has been always the same (I only forgot to put it in this stackoverflow post when creating it)

Answer (score 0):

The main issue that caused `self.cleaned_data['field']` to be empty for me is that I needed to use `form.field.html_name` instead of `form.field.name` for the name field of the template.

However, this isn't all that clear from the documentation provided by Django formtools. Here's an excerpt from my template page, so it's even clearer:

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label>{{ form.account_name.label }}</label>
  <input name="{{ form.account_name.html_name }}"
         value="{{ form.account_name.value|default_if_none:'' }}"
         class="form-control">
</div>
```